# Помогите исправить ошибку в sql запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

помогите исправить ошибку в данном sql запросе

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `product` `p`
    LEFT JOIN `product_to_category` `p2c` ON (`p`.`id` = p2c.product_id) WHERE p2c.category_id = 150
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT product_id FROM product_attribute WHERE (attribute_id = 37 AND attribute_value_id IN (1504))
    group by product_id having count(*) = 1) pa ON `pa`.`product_id`=`p`.`id`
    ORDER BY (SELECT count(*) FROM product_price WHERE product_id = p.id) DESC LIMIT 12
```

Движок говорит о не верном синтаксисе рядом с `'INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id FROM product_attribute WHERE (attribute_id = 37'`

Если же поменять запросы местами LEFT JOIN и INNER JOIN то ошибка пропадает.

Comment: Если с ходу, то всегда думал, что цепочку джойнов завершить надо, а потом уже `where p2c.category_id = 150`...

Comment: :) Действительно, спасибо!